# Password fields blank

Tags: sql-server

We have an SQL export of our old PSA system and we need to extract some credentials from it. For some reason, executing a subset of the built-in view query shows the password fields as either `NULL` (understandably) or simply blank but none of the other 144 columns have this problem and, as far as I'm aware, the data should be there.

[image]

I know little about SQL but this seems to not be masking at least as that displays `x`s instead.

This is a difficult scenario to research because everyone else **wants** to be able to hide passwords, whereas I'm trying to recover them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database does not contain those data and it’s therefore NULL.

Probably your export from PSA foes not include any passwords.